# Testing EventEmitter event handlers

Tags: node.js, jestjs, event-handling

I want to test handing of an event (test if I have subscribed after a connection has been established):

```
import * as mqtt from 'mqtt';

export function testEmitter() {

  console.info(`Connecting to MQTT Server ${process.env.MQTT_URL} ...`);

  const client  = mqtt.connect(process.env.MQTT_URL, {
    username: process.env.MQTT_USER,
    password: process.env.MQTT_PASS,
    clientId: process.env.MQTT_CLIENT ?? 'checkmk_zigbee2mqtt',
  });

  client.on('connect', () => {

    console.info(`Subscribing to MQTT topic ...`);

    client.subscribe(`${process.env.SOME_TOPIC}/#`, { rh: 1, qos: 0 }, () => {});

};
```

My jest code looks like:

```
export class MqttClientMock extends events.EventEmitter {
  subscribe = jest.fn((topic: string, opts: any, callback: ClientSubscribeCallback) => {
    callback(undefined, []);
  });
  publish = jest.fn();
  unsubscribe = jest.fn();
}


describe('emitterTests', () => {

  const mqtt = require('mqtt');

  let client:       MqttClientMock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    client = new MqttClientMock();

    mqtt.connect = jest.fn();
  })

  it('should subscribe after the connection is established', (done) => {

    testEmitter();

    expect(mqtt.connect).toBeCalled();

    client.emit('connect', new Error('you did wrong'));

    expect(client.subscribe).toBeCalled();

    done();
  })
});
```

I am not able to create a valid test on any attempt that I made.

Above implementation gives error message: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')`

Some other attempts (i.e. making testEmitter async) tell me that logging 'Subscribing to MQTT topic  ...' is done after termination

How can I write a good test that validates the handling after a connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you set `client` as the return value for `mqtt.connect` after mocking it in `beforeEach`?

```
beforeEach(() => {
   client = new MqttClientMock();

   mqtt.connect = jest.fn();
   mqtt.connect.mockReturnValue(client)
})
```

Comment: Yes, that was a silly one. Thanks